# "QtQuick" version 2.0 is not installed for Qt Quick Application

Tags: qt, qt-quick

In Qt 5.0.2 with MinGW47_32 I finished coding my project using Qt Quick UI project. Now I would like to deploy it.
In Qt Quick UI project it is impossible. So I want to copy my project files to Qt Quick Application project and deploy it, but there I have error: qrc:/main.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick" version 2.0 is not installed.
In Qt Quick UI project I don't have this error.

At the top of my project I am using: import QtQuick 2.0.

Can someone help me, how to avoid this error?

Comment: What command do you use? Command line or Qt Creator?

Comment: I am using Qt Creator.